# Firestore rules: why the caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection with documents that have the following fields

- uid: it is the user ID of the user who created the document
- anotherId: it is another id
- andAnotherId: it is another id
- date: it is the date of creation in seconds plus 1,000,000 seconds

[image]

In flutter I have the following query

```
    _firestore
      .collection('subscriptions')
      .where('anotherId', isEqualTo: '1')
      .where('andAnotherId', isEqualTo: '2')
      .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateInSeconds)
      .limit(1)
      .get()
      .then(....
```

I would like to set up a rule where only the user who created the document can read the document. I have written the following but it is not working. Does anyone know why??

```
    match /subscriptions/{item} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null
                  && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
   }
```

Note that it works if I write this rule (but I would like to avoid other user can read documents created by other users)

```
    match /subscriptions/{item} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
   }
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a document from that collection? Also try logging current user's UID and check if that matched with the one in your document.

Comment: Hello, I have added a screenshot of my document. The uid in firestore is the same that I see in my flutter app when I login

Comment: Note that some document in my collection may not have the uid field however the rest of the query should return a document with the uid field. I am not sure if all the documents must have the uid field to have this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved by changing the query as follow but still I am not getting why it did not work before

```
_firestore
  .collection('subscriptions')
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
  .where('anotherId', isEqualTo: '1')
  .where('andAnotherId', isEqualTo: '2')
  .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateInSeconds)
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(....
```

Comment: It didn't work before because [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they merely check whether the read operation matches the condition. So the `request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid` in your rules says "to allow a read operation it must query only for documents whose `uid` field is the same as the logged on user". Since you added that condition to the query in this answer, it is now allowed by the rule.

Comment: I see. Thank you